# Identification of ground cover in small decideous forest (zone 5B)

Tags: identification, ground-cover

This morning I was walking in Saint-Bruno national park in Quebec, Canada and I happened upon this large patch of ground cover. It was particularly striking as it seemed to be an evergreen herbaceous plant. Apart from conifers I don't remember seeing green anywhere at this time of year in the woods or forests of Quebec.

This leads me to believe it might not be an indigenous plant.

It was located in a zone 5B small deciduous forest that is near a small lake and very close to a suburban area.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well it looks remarkably like Pachysandra terminalis to me, an evergreen groundcover which does well in shady conditions. Tends to look a bit floppy, as per your picture, when its in sun or if its been very cold.  See link below for info

http://www.oakleafgardening.com/plants/pachysandra-terminalis/

and a clearer pic here, though not showing flower buds - should flower April/May, any time soon

http://espacepourlavie.ca/en/ground-covers

Comment: It was cold when I took the picture. Around -5 Celsius

Comment: That'll be why it looks a bit floppy then!

Comment: What a beautiful crop of Pachysandra!!  Unbelievable.  Lucky lucky you!